# Work done in Free Expansion of an Ideal gas

Tags: work, ideal-gas

We define the work done in gaseous expansion as (External Force)*(Displacement of the piston)

The work done in free expansion, therefore, comes out to be 0 as the external pressure is 0.

But if we let the gas expand to infinity, then the work done will be (Infinity*0) which should limit to a constant value.

If there was no work done in any intermediate step, how can there still be net work done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of this argument is the fact that the external pressure is *always* zero, so multiplying zero by a number as big as you like (even "infinity") will return zero. You could have a result different from zero only if external force *approaches* to zero as the piston expands, in this case the total work will assume a finite value, but as you may guess the external force is not always going to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication property of zero states that the product of any number and zero is zero.

https://science.howstuffworks.com/math-concepts/zero4.htm

So the work done is zero regardless of how much expansion occurs.

Hope this helps.